# Format word table row from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

- Need to select several rows in word table from excel and then format
- Copied table from excel to word
- Can select a single row
- Need to format selected row by adding space before in each cell
- Need to do for several rows prefer to select range of cells and format all the same

---

**Code:**

```
Set objword = createobject(“word.application”)

Set objdoc = objword.documents.add

With objword 

‘Lines of code for pagesetup working ok

‘Then paste excel table to word working ok

.selection paste

.visible = true

‘Have code sorted to select single row working ok

.activedocument.table(1).row(3).select

End with
```

Need to have code to select several rows

Then format by adding space before in each cell or entire row

Everything tried gives me unsupported function

Comment: Shouldn't `activedocument.table(1).row(3).select` be `activedocument.tables(1).rows(3).select` ?

Comment: Please include what you've tried, which line(s) cause(s) the error(s) and exactly what the error messages are. Also, it's not clear what you need, exactly. "Adding a space before in each cell..." - a space before *what*, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notes:**

- Will copy the Selected table in Excel to Word Document
- Loop through all it's cell
- You can change their Text , add space in front.
- Skip rows in the loop using If condition.

**Code:**

```
Sub tb_copy()

Selection.Copy

Set objWord = CreateObject("word.application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

objWord.Visible = True

With objDoc

.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False

For i = 1 To .tables(1).Rows.Count

    For j = 1 To .tables(1).Columns.Count

    Debug.Print .tables(1).cell(i, j).Range.Text

    Next
Next

End With

End Sub
```

**Problem:**

- .Selection.paste does not work
- Need with statement with ObjDoc